# How to access a field of a namedtuple using a variable for the field name?

Tags: python, namedtuple

I can access elements of a named tuple by name as follows(*):

```
from collections import namedtuple
Car = namedtuple('Car', 'color mileage')
my_car = Car('red', 100)
print my_car.color
```

But how can I use a variable to specify the name of the field I want to access? E.g.

```
field = 'color'
my_car[field] # doesn't work
my_car.field # doesn't work
```

My actual use case is that I'm iterating through a pandas dataframe with `for row in data.itertuples()`. I am doing an operation on the value from a particular column, and I want to be able to specify the column to use by name as a parameter to the method containing this loop.

(*) [example taken from here](https://dbader.org/blog/writing-clean-python-with-namedtuples). I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: `getattr(my_car, field)` or `my_car._asdict()[field]`.

Comment: Also try `mycar[field]` but then you might iterate using `for row in data`.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can use `getattr`

```
getattr(my_car, field)
```

Answer (score 11):

The 'getattr' answer works, but there is another option which is slightly faster.

```
idx = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(list(df), start=1)}
for row in df.itertuples(name=None):
   example_value = row[idx['product_price']]
```

## Explanation

Make a dictionary mapping the column names to the row position. Call 'itertuples' with "name=None". Then access the desired values in each tuple using the
indexes obtained using the column name from the dictionary.

1. Make a dictionary to find the indexes.

`idx = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(list(df), start=1)}`

2. Use the dictionary to access the desired values by name in the row tuples

```
for row in df.itertuples(name=None):
   example_value = row[idx['product_price']]
```

Note: Use `start=0` in `enumerate` if you call itertuples with `index=False`

Here is a working example showing both methods and the timing of both methods.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit

data_length = 3 * 10**5
fake_data = {
    "id_code": list(range(data_length)),
    "letter_code": np.random.choice(list('abcdefgz'), size=data_length),
    "pine_cones": np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=data_length),
    "area": np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=data_length),
    "temperature": np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=data_length),
    "elevation": np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=data_length),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(fake_data)


def iter_with_idx():
    result_data = []
    
    idx = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(list(df), start=1)}
    
    for row in df.itertuples(name=None):
        
        row_calc = row[idx['pine_cones']] / row[idx['area']]
        result_data.append(row_calc)
        
    return result_data

      
def iter_with_getaatr():
    
    result_data = []
    for row in df.itertuples():
        row_calc = getattr(row, 'pine_cones') / getattr(row, 'area')
        result_data.append(row_calc)
        
    return result_data
    

dict_idx_method = timeit.timeit(iter_with_idx, number=100)
get_attr_method = timeit.timeit(iter_with_getaatr, number=100)

print(f'Dictionary index Method {dict_idx_method:0.4f} seconds')
print(f'Get attribute method {get_attr_method:0.4f} seconds')
```

Result:

```
Dictionary index Method 49.1814 seconds
Get attribute method 80.1912 seconds
```

I assume the difference is due to lower overhead in creating a tuple vs a named tuple and also lower overhead in accessing it by the index rather than getattr but both of those are just guesses. If anyone knows better please comment.

I have not explored how the number of columns vs number of rows effects the timing results.

Answer (score 6):

since python version 3.6 one could inherit from `typing.NamedTuple`

```py
import typing as tp


class HistoryItem(tp.NamedTuple):
    inp: str
    tsb: float
    rtn: int
    frequency: int = None

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, int):
            item = self._fields[item]
        return getattr(self, item)

    def get(self, item, default=None):
        try:
            return self[item]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError, IndexError):
            return default


item = HistoryItem("inp", 10, 10, 10)

print(item[0])  # 'inp'
print(item["inp"])  # 'inp'
```

Comment: This needs to be recognised as the modern answer.

Comment: Python 3.6 is not required for this, you can use the `collections.namedtuple` class factory and achieve the same thing.

Comment: Also, `tp.NamedTuple.__getitem__` will give you an attribute error. `tp.NamedTuple` isn't a real class... it's kind of ugly, actually, it is merely used as a vehicle for metaclass magic that eventually calls `collections.namedtuple` to return a class derived from `tuple`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for pointing out. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of accessing them can be:

```
field_idx = my_car._fields.index(field)
my_car[field_idx]
```

Extract index of the field and then use it to index the namedtuple.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
for i,x in enumerate(my_car._fields):
    print(x, my_car[i])
```