# How to enable row[col_name] syntax with Namedtuple Pandas from df.itertuples()

Tags: python, pandas, namedtuple

We have a DataFrame with many columns and need to cycle through the rows with df.itertuples(). Many column names are in variables and accessing the namedtuple `row` with getattr() works fine but is not very readable with many column accesses. Is there a way to enable the `row[col_name]` syntax? E.g with a subclassed NamedTuple like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65301971/360265?

```
import pandas as pd

col_name = 'b'

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2.}, {'a': 3,'b': 4.}])
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row.a)  # Using row._asdict() would disable this syntax
    print(getattr(row, col_name))  # works fine but is not as readable as row[col_name]
    print(row[col_name]) # how to enable this syntax?
```

Wrapping `row` in the following `Frame` class is a solution but not really a pythonic one.

```
class Frame:
    def __init__(self, namedtuple: NamedTuple):
        self.namedtuple = namedtuple

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.namedtuple, item)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.namedtuple, item)
```

Comment: What is the problem with row._asdict()[col_name], or even better save it to a new variable and use it?

Comment: I think you already found out: `row.a` is not possible with Dict

Answer (score 2):

Use [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

```
import pandas as pd

col_name = 'b'

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}])
for row in df.to_dict('records'):
    print(row[col_name])
```

**Output**

```
2
4
```

If you want to keep both notations, a possible approach would be to do:

```
def iterdicts(tuples):
    yield from ((tup, tup._asdict()) for tup in tuples)


df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}])
for tup, row in iterdicts(df.itertuples()):
    print(tup.a)
    print(row[col_name])
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: both options certainly work, thanks. It's mainly a question about improving readability and  I think both are on the same level as the question.

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach to yours, just using `df.iterrows()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3,'b': 4}])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row.b) 
    print(getattr(row, 'b')) 
    print(row['b'])
```

These lines were tested using pandas versions 0.20.3 and 1.0.1.

Comment: that solves the question asked. We always have different data types in columns that's why I forgot to specify it in my question (will add it now). That's also the reason we never use iterrows() as it looses the dtypes.